# Oracle Advanced Queuing Service via Node.js -- dequeue a Message Gives Error Message Error: ORA-25215: user_data type and queue type do not match

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb, oracle-aq

I get the following message when trying to dequeue a message in a Node.js program.  I am using node-oracledb Version 5.5.0.  The documentation says that this is an error for enqueueing a message.  The message that i am trying to retrieve (dequeue) is a simple object.  I have tried passing the object type as well, but that does not seem to work either.  I have no problem enqueuing a message from a different route inside this same node.js program.  Thanks in advance for any help and/or passive aggressive insults.

Error: ORA-25215: user_data type and queue type do not match

```
 async dequeueOne() {

    const pool = await sow.getPool();

    const connection = await pool.getConnection();

    const queue = await connection.getQueue(queueName, payloadType: "Name of Object Type");

    queue.deqOptions.wait = oracledb.AQ_DEQ_NO_WAIT;

    let msg ;

    try {

        msg = await queue.deqOne();

    }

    catch(e) {

        console.log(`Error dequeuing: '${e}'`);

    }

    finally {

        await connection.commit();

        await connection.close();

    }

    return msg;

}
```

Comment: Can you share the queue & object definition? And Oracle client & DB versions?  When you say you tried passing the object type, did you mean like https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v5.5.0/examples/aqobject.js#L90 ?

Comment: Exactly, I included the message type.  When I do include the message type, I do get a dbObject that includes the object definition, but no actual data.  https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/dbobject.html#. For instance, dbObject.isCollection returns false.  Or msg.payload.attributes returns    the object definition (names, but no values).

Comment: const queue = await connection.getQueue(queueName, payloadType: "Object Type");  This is the attempt that I am describing above using the 5.50 version.

Comment: You'll need to share a reproducible test case - including SQL to create the queue & object, and a runnable file that enqueues & dequeues.

Comment: OK.  I can get that together.  Right now msg.payload.attributes is working in that I get the object definition.  For instance, msg.payload.attributes['ID'] {type: 2010, typeName: 'NUMBER'} and msg.payload.attributes['TEXT'] {type: 2001, typeName: 'VARCHAR2'}.  I just do not get any values for ID and TEXT.

Comment: Also share your Oracle client & server versions so if I talk to our AQ team they have all the info to analyze.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for all your help.  The repository is a great reference.  I fixed the call above to include the name of the Object Type for PayloadType.  My next problem was that I was expecting msg.payload.attributes to include the actual values of my object attributes, not just the data type definition.  As it turns out, what I needed was msg.payload.ID, msg.payload.TEXT, etc....

Comment: I'm glad you solved it!